# In which quadrant is terminal side of angle 2$\theta$ and $\theta / 2$?

Tags: trigonometry

How do I find the quadrants of 2$\theta$ and $\theta /2$ if

sin $\theta$ = 4/5 is in 2nd quadrant.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "$\sin \theta = 4/5$ is in the second quadrant" is malformed.  It is a splice of two ideas: "$\sin \theta = 4/5$" and "$\theta$ is in the second quadrant".  It is indicative of confusion to say that the side length ratio $\frac{4}{5}$ is in any quadrant.

Since $\theta$ is in the second quadrant, $\dfrac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \pi$.  Dividing through by $2$, we find $\dfrac{\pi}{4} < \dfrac{\theta}{2} < \dfrac{\pi}{2}$, so $\dfrac{\theta}{2}$ is in the first quadrant.

We can also double this equation, $\pi < 2 \theta < 2 \pi$, so $2 \theta$ is in the third or fourth quadrants.  Sine is the same sign in both quadrants, so $\sin 2 \theta$ is of no use in discriminating between the two possibilities.  Cosine, however, is positive in the fourth quadrant and negative in the third quadrant, so the sign of cosine will resolve the question.  $\cos 2 \theta = 1 - 2 \sin^2(\theta) = 1- 2 (\frac{4}{5})^2 = 1 - \frac{32}{25} < 0$ and we find that $2\theta$ is in the third quadrant.

Comment: It's actually impossible to say *precisely* where $\theta/2$ lives, knowing only that $\theta$ is in the second quadrant. Perhaps, instead of $\theta \in (\frac \pi 2, \pi)$, instead we have that $\theta \in (-\pi, -\frac{3\pi}{2})$, in which case $\theta/2 \in (-\frac\pi2, -\frac{3\pi}{4})$. I realized this (thankfully *before*!) writing a precalc exam this semester. I think it's fair to *assume* the author intended $\theta/2$ to be in quadrant I, but ...

Comment: @pjs36 : Certainly, there is a problem with knowing which member of the coterminal family is *really* $\theta$.  If the author isn't going to give any more hints, however, I'm going to assume the minimal nonnegative member (unless this theta is actually the output of some expression that can be negative, for instance $3 \tan^{-1}(\text{[something negative]})$).